# Select from multiple tables and put them in a temporary table

Tags: mysql

I need to create a temporary table and put data from multiple tables in it.  In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table) they all select from one table. how to select from multiple tables? (All tables have exactly same columns)

**Edit:** tables have no relationship and they are 9 tables, but they all have same columns like id,username,password. each table contains information about specific users.

Comment: What is the relationship between the tables?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen they have no relationship.

Comment: Then the only option I see here would be to UNION together the tables, but that would only make sense if they have the same definition.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Union](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) can help you combine those two tables, and then you can use the `TEMPORARY` method!

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableTemp AS (SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2)
```

This would result in data from both your tables being "unified" into one table.

So with two tables like this:

**table1**

```
testCol | testCol2
--------+---------
   A    |     1
```

**table2**

```
testCol | testCol2
--------+---------
   B    |     2
```

the code above would return

**tableTemp**

```
testCol | testCol2
--------+---------
   A    |     1
   B    |     2
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, the code above was just an example! You would need to change variable names:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableTemp AS (SELECT * FROM [[NAME OF FIRST TABLE]] UNION SELECT * FROM [[NAME OF SECOND TABLE]])
```

Since you say you have 9 tables, you would just need to keep appending a UNION SELECT for each of those tables.
For example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableTemp AS (SELECT * FROM [[NAME OF FIRST TABLE]] UNION SELECT * FROM [[NAME OF SECOND TABLE]] UNION SELECT * FROM [[NAME OF THIRD TABLE]] UNION SELECT * FROM [[NAME OF FOURTH TABLE]] UNION SELECT * FROM [[NAME OF FIFTH TABLE]] UNION SELECT * FROM [[NAME OF SIXTH TABLE]] UNION SELECT * FROM [[NAME OF SEVENTH TABLE]] UNION SELECT * FROM [[NAME OF EIGTH TABLE]] UNION SELECT * FROM [[NAME OF NINTH TABLE]])
```

Comment: you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION SELECT * FROM table2)' at line 1

Comment: Well you would need to change the name of the tables you are selecting from... `table2` was only in my test! :)

Comment: This seems like it should work, but it looks like you actually can't create a temp table directly from a union. It returns the error that @eylay reported here in the comments. This answer provides a workaround to the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751787/3508398

Answer (score 0):

Try using joins and unions. And since u want temporary table alias will do.
For join, query will be as:

```
Select column_names from table1 join table2 on column_names
```

If you have more than 2 table, you can use chain of joins to get results.

See this link
 https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp&ved=0ahUKEwim456hiJLVAhUIVbwKHQ9SBzwQFggeMAA&usg=AFQjCNH2uk_VTd4skktAbnIq3dv1MlKD-g

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_3 AS SELECT 1st_table_id as union_id, 1st_table_username as union_username, 1st_table_password as union_password FROM table_1 UNION SELECT 2nd_table_id as union_id, 2nd_table_username as union_username, 2nd_table_password as union_password FROM table_2
```

Change the "union_id", "union_username" and "union_password" as per the new column name of the new table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but the code in the accepted answer here results in a syntax error.

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751787/3508398), you can't create a table (or a temp table) directly from a union. You can stick the union in a sub-query though, like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableTemp AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM table2
    )
)
```